# How can I select and highlight Items with the same indexes in two listboxes? VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, listbox

My problem is that I want to select and highlight both items in 2 listboxes in just 1 click.

My example is in the picture below. If I click `CHEM102`, the number in its right side, which is `1` (which is in the other listbox), should be highlighted also. If I click `CHEM102L`, the `3` (which is in the other listbox) on the right side should also be highlighted on 1 click.

[image: CLICK THIS TO SEE IMAGE EXAMPLE]

I tried:

```
Listbox1.SelectedIndex = Listbox2.SelectedIndex
```

and

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)   Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
  Dim i As Integer = ListBox2.FindString(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
    If (i <> -1 AndAlso ListBox2.SelectedIndex <> i) Then
        ListBox2.SelectedIndex = i
    End If
End Sub
```

Please, help me. I'm just newbie here who's seeking for help. Thank you so much. please be good to me.

Comment: You are probably using the wrong control if that's what you are trying to do.. Use a listview or a dataviewgrid instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ListBox2.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
End Sub
```

Comment: HE needs it to go both ways though

Comment: Hi, Im sorry. I tried to put it in both listboxes, and it worked! thank you so much! <3